# Activiti to Flowable, how to migrate .bpmn files process definition

Tags: activiti, bpmn, flowable

I am migrating an application bpmn engine from Activiti 5 to Flowable 6. Currently I have an issue as my current process definition to used in Actitivi 5 is .bpmn files, so if I want to used them in Flowable 6, do I need to do any modification?

P/s: I read the Flowable migration guide here https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/migration/, but don't found any information for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to do any changes to the .bpmn files. Flowable can read bpmn files created for Activiti 5.